# SQL Server Compare Datetime with Char

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am going over a legacy system where a "date" column `report_date` in a table `t_results` is set up as char(25).

Name of the column is report_date and it type is `report_date (char(25),null)`

A sproc utilizes the table  as

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[s_report]
(
    @report_date_from DATETIME,
    @report_date_to DATETIME,
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT * 
FROM 
    t_results
WHERE
    report_date >= @report_date_from AND report_date <= @report_date_to
ORDER BY report_id
```

When I run this as `EXEC s_report '9/4/2018','10/2/2018'` it runs good and I get expected result.

When I run the query below (which is same as sproc), I get no results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    t_results
WHERE
    report_date >= '09/04/2018' AND report_date <= '10/2/2018'
```

I am not sure how the sproc is working. Any idea or pointers as to how I compare char with datetime in my where clause?

Comment: your second query is not the same. It uses char for dates and they need to be converted to dates, and that can be a problem with regional settings

Comment: http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Comment: SP is converting the strings to datetime as that's the type of the input variables, your other query does not do that and performs a lexical comparison.

Comment: This works only by the grace of `DATETIME` having a higher [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) than `CHAR`, so that all text fields in the table are converted before being compared. Terrible, terrible practice -- but then, I guess that's why it's a legacy system.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for the link. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stored procedure is making a conversion to DateTime. When one of the types is different, SQL Server is doing an implicit conversion when it is making the check thus the SP code is implicitly like:

```
where cast(report_date as datetime) >= '09/04/2018' and cast(report_date as datetime) <= '10/2/2018'
```

Note: Passing a date string like that is not safe and server settings dependent. Pass like '20180904' and '20181002'.

Answer (score 2):

I think your proc essentially does this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_results
WHERE report_date >= CAST ('09/04/2018' AS DATETIME) 
  AND report_date <= CAST ('10/2/2018' AS DATETIME)
```